# If $3f(x+2)+4f(\frac{1}{x+2})=4x$ where $x$ is not equal to $-2$, find $f(4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $3f(x+2)+4f(\frac{1}{x+2})=4x$ where $x$ is not equal to $-2$,  find $f(4)$

I substituted value of 2 in the function. I couldn't think of what else could be done

Comment: Click on 'edited' and you'll see what changes were made. I fixed the formatting.

Comment: $1/(x+2)$ @ajotatxe Now, you understood my question?

Comment: As you can see, omission of brackets can lead to ambiguity and $1/x+2$
 will be taken to mean $\frac{1}{x}+2$ - don't forget them.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 kindly learn mathjax....  use brackets too.

Comment: What range of values can $x$ and $f$ take? $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $x=2$ and $x=-\frac{7}{4}$ and solve a system of two equations involving $f(4)$ and $f(1/4)$.

Comment: How do you know that $x=-7/4$? @dromastyx

Comment: @SakuziMarkel $\frac{1}{x+2}$ is the inverse of $x+2$. So you want to find an $x$ such that 1) $x+2=4$ and 2) $x+2=1/4$ and you will end up with equations involving only $f(4)$ and $f(1/4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$3f(4)+4f\left(  \frac14\right)=8$$

It would be great if we know $f\left(  \frac14\right)$.

Can you evaluate $$3f\left(  \frac14\right)+4f(4)?$$

After which, solve for $f(4)$ and $\left( \frac14 \right)$.

Comment: Thanks you pointing out the mistake.